# Gap between inline-block elements with whitespace: nowrap and overflow: scroll parent element

Tags: css, overflow, whitespace, css-tables, nowrap

I wanted to display a table (but I'm using div) that will scroll the overflow since the table is long. The problem I'm getting at is there's an unknown gap between my divs.

And here's the snippet: what's causing the unwanted gaps between columns (divs)?

```css
.mobile-cross-reference {
  border: 1px solid #2980b9;
  color: #333;
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  width: 96%;
}
  
.m-grid-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.m-grid-header {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.m-grid-header,
.m-grid-row {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.m-grid-header-col {
  background-color: #2980b9 !important;
}

.m-grid-row-inline {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.m-grid-col {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  padding: 1% 0 1% 1%;
}

.m-grid-col:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.m-grid-col3 {
  width: 31%;
}

.m-grid-inline {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-cross-reference m-grid-scroll">
      <div class="m-grid-header m-grid-row-inline">
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Bourns</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">BI Tech</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Dale/Vishay</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Philips/Mepco</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Murata</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Panasonic</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Spectrol</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Mil Spec</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-grid-row m-grid-row-inline">
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Bourns</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">BI Tech</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Dale/Vishay</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Philips/Mepco</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Murata</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Panasonic</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Spectrol</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Mil Spec</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone comes across this problem, there are two things to be said here.

1. As observed already there is something off with the markup. Sometimes when copying code from somewhere else, whitespace is not exactly whitespace and is actually rendered as a character. I am almost certain that this is the case here, just too lazy to copy the snippet and check.
2. Using `font-size: 0` on the row element and `font-size: <whatever-value-should-be>` on the columns themselves fixes the issue without meddling with the HTML. This works because setting font-size to 0 on the row makes the "hidden characters" disappear completely - their font size is 0. The font-size should then be restored in the children since it (i.e. 0) is inherited.

Comment: Exactly! I read [this tutorial on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more info. Thank You! :) So, what happens is that You have for example: `<div> LINE_BREAK INDENTATION <p>text</p> LINE_BREAK INDENTATION <p>txt2</p> LINE_BREAK </div>`. That `INDENTATION` is white-space, and your browser renders that as well. We want our code formatted nicely, so we want white-spaces there and that is causing the problem.

Comment: Generally proper code formatting should not introduce this problem. Although, if you are rendering server-side using e.g. PHP with inline HTML or something of the sort, then there might be additional caveats with how the language interprets the markup, which I can't comment on.

Comment: I solved my problem by removing the whitespaces in html, but [as shown on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements), it is not the only way. I agree with You on the second part. Thanks for replying! :)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, the white space between the div tags. See the first columns.

```css
.mobile-cross-reference {
  border: 1px solid #2980b9;
  color: #333;

}
  
.m-grid-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.m-grid-header {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.m-grid-header,
.m-grid-row {

  width: 100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:block;
}

.m-grid-header-col {
  background-color: #2980b9 !important;
}

.m-grid-row-inline {
  background-color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.m-grid-col {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;

}

.m-grid-col:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.m-grid-col3 {
  width: 31%;
}

.m-grid-inline {
  display: inline-block;

  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-cross-reference m-grid-scroll">
      <div class="m-grid-header m-grid-row-inline"><div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Bourns</div><div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">BI Tech</div><div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Dale/Vishay</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Philips/Mepco</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Murata</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Panasonic</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Spectrol</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3 m-grid-header-col">Mil Spec</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-grid-row m-grid-row-inline">
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Bourns</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">BI Tech</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Dale/Vishay</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Philips/Mepco</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Murata</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Panasonic</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Spectrol</div>
        <div class="m-grid-col m-grid-inline m-grid-col3">Mil Spec</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: well, that's actually the problem, columns that were hidden has whitespaces. i cant seem to remove it anyhow.